# Is it possible to disable Findbugs Sensor for specific java project with sonar-scanner

Tags: android, sonarqube, findbugs

I have an android project and was asked to setup sonar analysis.

There is findbugs plugin installed on the Sonarqube server and I cannot remove it as other java projects are using it.

The problem is I don't want the findbugs analysis, but it looks like it is mandatory when I config the sonar-project.properties like this:

```
# Language
sonar.language=java
sonar.profile=Android Lint
```

[image]

I tried

```
sonar.findbugs.skip=true
sonar.findbugs.disabled=true
```

but no luck

so how can I disable the findbugs sensor for this specific project?

Answer (score 0):

FindBugs is executed here because the quality profile (rule set) you're using includes FindBugs rules. To avoid FindBugs execution, create a profile with no FindBugs rules in it, and assign your project to be analyzed with that profile. You can make the assignment in Project **Administration > Quality Profiles**.

**Update** It seems that the FindBugs sensor runs if the plugin is loaded in the  instance - whether or not you're using any of its rules. The only way to keep it from running & save that time is to uninstall.

Comment: but I'm using "Android Lint", from the quality profile page, look like none rules from findbugs are there

Comment: Removing findbug rules from the quality profile only makes sense if you want to eliminate findbugs report for the entire project.  For a multi-module maven project, what if I want to skip findbugs for a single module, but run it on all the other modules?  e.g.  I have one module full of generated-code (not worth findbugs checking), with real code in other modules.

Comment: Love it when people downvote because they don't like what the truth is

Answer (score 0):

If there is no FindBugs rule activated in the Quality Profile used by this project then it looks like you're impacted by a bug in the FindBugs Plugin:

> [Issue #37](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-findbugs/issues/37)  - *FindBugs plugin should not start an analysis if no rules are enabled*

Answer (score -1):

Currently, I think it can be resolved by https://github.com/spotbugs/sonar-findbugs/issues/50

On SonarQube server, under project administration > general settings >java > increase findbugs Timeout

Comment: As external resources are not-reliable, you should post the most important informations into your answer.

Comment: Giving findbugs more time to process is not a valid solution if I really want to not run findbugs at all on a given maven module.  In my situation, findbugs is taking a long time because its operating on something inappropriate (generated code in one particular module) - I don't want to give it more time, I want to turn it off for this module (only).